# React Native: How to load Lottie file from local path

Tags: react-native, lottie, react-native-fs

I use `react-native-fs` to download a Lottie file (json) from a remote server. After saving it to the filesystem I get a path like `/Users/marlon/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8E0A092D0E86/data/Containers/Data/Application/AADD60D8DFAD/Documents/animation.json`.

Is there now any way to use that filepath as a source for `LottieView`? I tried various approaches, but neither of them succeeded:

```
var path = '/Users/marlon/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8E0A092D0E86/data/Containers/Data/Application/AADD60D8DFAD/Documents/animation.json'

<LottieView source={{ uri: path }} />
<LottieView source={{ uri: 'file:/' + path }} />
<LottieView source={{ uri: 'file://' + path }} />
<LottieView source={{ uri: 'file://' + path, isStatic: true }} />
```

**ANSWER**

Its ok to just pass the animation file as a javascript object to the `LottieView`. So what I did now, was opening the file with `react-native-fs` and parsing it with `JSON.parse`. The final result looks like:

```
RNFS.readFile(animations.congratsAnimation).then(res => {
    this.setState({ animation: JSON.parse(res) });
}
...
<LottieView source={this.state.animation} />
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem but your path starts with a `/` and it will create a path something like `uri : 'file:///Users/....'` try removing `/` from your path and run it again.

Comment: That didn't do the trick

Comment: Passing the javascript object to the LottieView did the work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **require()** function while referencing the path for the resources.
For example you can do something like:

```
var path = require('/Users/marlon/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8E0A092D0E86/data/Containers/Data/Application/AADD60D8DFAD/Documents/animation.json');
```

or

```
<LottieView source = {require('/Users/marlon/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8E0A092D0E86/data/Containers/Data/Application/AADD60D8DFAD/Documents/animation.json')} />
```

Comment: As far as I know `require` will not work here since it will resolve its dependencies at build time, and the file will not exist at build time

Answer (score 0):

You should not hardcode the downloaded json file path, but rather keep it on a device's storage, e.g. Picture folder:

```
npm install --save react-native-fetch-blob

const { config, fs } = RNFetchBlob
RNFetchBlob.config({ path : RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir + '/animation.png' +  })
.fetch('GET', 'http://example.com/file/whichever', {
    'Cache-Control' : 'no-store'
})
.then((res) => {
    // where the file is, keep it as state.animationPath
    this.setState(animationPath: res.path()) 
})

//render()
<LottieView source={{require(this.state.animationPath)}, isStatic: true }} />
```

Comment: I do actually fetch the file like u described, but what doesn't work is `<LottieView source={{ uri: this.state.animationPath, isStatic: true }} />`. Can u confirm that this works for you?

Comment: I guess you mean `<LottieView source={{ uri: require(this.state.animationPath), isStatic: true }} />`? When I do this I get `Error: Unknown named module: '/Users/....`. Independently if I try it with `file://` prefix or not.